# angular ng serve command throws error: An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist

Tags: angular, serve

I am trying to up my local angular dev env using ng serve, it was working perfectly fine a day back, but now every time I run ng serve or npm start it throws an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist.

I have tried running ng serve in one of my different project, it works there.

not sure what it causing this error

Comment: are you executing `ng serve` from the correct directory?

Comment: update or reinstall angular cli

Comment: I have the exact same error and updating or reinstalling doesn't help for either angular/cli nor angular itself

Answer (score 94):

**Make sure the name of the project in your `angular.json` matches what is being called from your `package.json` scripts section.**

This is how I discovered the problem. I was getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist.
See "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-XcQsPs\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When I went to that log file, I saw this:

```
[error] Error: Project does not exist.
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.findProjectTarget (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:94:23)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:13:39)
    at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:175:55)
    at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:218:35)
    at RunCommand.run (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js:14:25)
    at RunCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Adam\source\repos\TechScore.Express\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:134:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

So I opened `node-modules-architect-host.js:94:23` and saw this:

```
const projectDefinition = this._workspace.projects.get(target.project);
if (!projectDefinition) {
    throw new Error('Project does not exist.');
}
```

I have no idea why they throw an error like this without telling you which project does not exist. So I changed the file to be like this:

```
throw new Error('Project does not exist. ' + target.project);
```

Now, when I build, I get an error like this instead:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist. client-app
```

Finally I can see who the culprit is! A global search for "client-app" showed me that it was being used from `package.json`, but my project in `angular.json` was "ClientApp". Changing all references of "ClientApp" to "client-app" fixed the problem for me.

Comment: There should have added this little piece `('Project does not exist. ' + target.project);` there which saves a lot of time.

Comment: This is a great solution and explanation! Thanks

Comment: When I update my node-modules-architect-host.js file as to your suggestions, I don't even get the new Error message? Any Idea how that could happen?

Comment: @dfbenny, I would double-check that the correct file was modified, that the file was not overwritten by the old version after you modified it, and that a cached version was not being used (maybe clear package cache?).

Comment: Name of the project is now included in _angular-devkit-architect-builds_ since august 2020.

Comment: I tried this but the error changed to "Project target does not exist".

Answer (score 20):

Similar to issue mentioned by adam0101,
the issue got fixed for me by changing the project name. Infact package.json and angular.json names can be different( at least for me), but within angular.json, the naming was consistent

## Old

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "e-admin": {   ======NAME USED HERE=======
      "root": "",
...
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "eAdmin:build"    ===NAME USED HERE====
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "eAdmin:build:production"  <===NAME USED HERE
            }
          }
        },
```

## Modified

```
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "e-admin": {
      "root": "",
...
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "e-admin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "e-admin:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps me not to waste my time,

Comment: Agree, names can be different. In fact, you might have a command defined in `angular.json`, but even not existing in `package.json` and it'll still work.

Answer (score 9):

please check projects name and defaultProject are same

> testapp

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": { // here 
    "testapp": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
```

.....................

```
"defaultProject": "testapp",
```

please try

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you angular.json have this config

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": { // here 
        "testapp": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
```

Comment: this application contain custom ng library I am building from,

Answer (score 6):

I match the values in angular.json & package.json and my problem was solved

angular.json:

```
"projects": {
    "step1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      ...,
      ...,
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "step1",
  ...,
  ...,
```

Comment: tried it but error still project "app" does not exist where I have change the name to something else than not "app"

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue changing the target in tsconfig.json from es2015 to es5

Comment: if you're getting reported issue suddenly without adding or removing any module..... this method will work thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

@adam0101 The solution helped a lot! Thank you!!!

But I had to add a console.log(target):

```
const projectDefinition = this._workspace.projects.get(target.project);
if (!projectDefinition) {
    console.log(target)
    throw new Error('Project does not exist.');
}
```

And I found in the package.json the wrong project name over a global search:

[image: The failure:]

Answer (score 2):

Project name in angular.json must be the same at every property where is needed.

And take good care of letter case, even in paths, at angular.json.

Windows doesn't complain, but Angular does!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with **Angular Universal**. For me it was the simplest thing. It is **npm run dev:ssr** not **ng run dev:ssr**.  However, it is **ng run myproject:serve-ssr**.  Watch for differences between **ng** and **npm**.

Answer (score 2):

I duplicated a project and changed its name getting me this error. Fixed it by changing the project name everywhere else in angular.json.

For example

```
    "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "YourNewProjectName:serve"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "devServerTarget": "YourNewProjectName:serve:production"
                }
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this issue. It's likely you didn't run `npm install` or `yarn` before calling the run script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an existing project, you might need want to check the `codeCoverageExclude` inside `angular.json` and see if your `*.spec.ts` files are defined inside the array.

You might find your files excluded on the test.

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works using

```
npm run cordova:run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path of "styles" in the angular.json should be

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

instead of

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

And also remove one dot from the "scripts"

```
 "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```