# ng run project:deploy - Project target does not exist

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, azure-devops

I have a working production build for Angular Web App.
I have an active subscription on my Azure Account (Free Tier) with an AppService Plan, App Service, Resource group, Storage Account, KeyVault, SQL Server & SignalR.

[image]

I want to deploy my web App using Azure. My Source control is Azure DevOps.

I have followed tutorials:

https://medium.com/@waelkdouh/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-azure-devops-f3ba35a0ae4d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment

https://angular.schule/blog/2019-08-ng-deploy

https://medium.com/@kevinding0218/deploy-angular-8-application-to-azure-app-service-paas-using-azure-devops-repo-cd-c3294cd52193

But basically always fail at the last step:
ng run :deploy

Depending on what I enter for  I get two types of error messages.

If I enter ng run projectName:deploy (this is what I believe to be the correct name), I get

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist.
```

If I enger ng run projectname:deploy (this is my projectname with wrong casing), I get

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project "projectname" does not exist.
```

So It seems to trigger some different Error message inside

```
clientapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
```

I tried tweaking it as in [Angular8 : ng run => 'Project target does not exist.' when using i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111480/angular8-ng-run-project-target-does-not-exist-when-using-i18n/60983433#60983433) but it didn't make me any wiser.

my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "projectName": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": true,
            "extractCss": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/projectName",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [ "src/assets", "src/manifest.webmanifest", "src/web.config" ],
            "styles": [
          
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "serviceWorker": true,
          "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "projectName:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "projectName:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": ["styles.css"],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets", 
          "src/web.config",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "projectName:serve"
      }
    },
    "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/dogface/server",
        "main": "server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "outputHashing": "media",
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "sourceMap": false,
          "optimization": true
        }
      }
    },
    "serve-ssr": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "projectName:build",
        "serverTarget": "projectName:server"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production",
          "serverTarget": "projectName:server:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production",
        "serverTarget": "projectName:server:production",
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ]
      },
 
    
      }
    }

  },
  "defaultProject": "projectName"
}
```

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>DogFace</title>
    <base href="/"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  </head>
  <body>
  <app-root>
  Loading...
  </app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've been trying for days now, running in circles. I have updated to Angular 11, did ng add @azure/ng-deploy (which says after logging in: You don't have any active subscriptions, but when I az storage account list in CMD-Shell, I see my actual subscription and when I az login in CMD: [image] ), I removed & readded node_modules folder, changed es2015 to es5 in tsconfig.json, did npm install before build --prod, authorized my azure account from cmd-shell.

Everything suggested in this thread did not work either [angular ng serve command throws error: An unhandled exception occurred: Project does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585781/angular-ng-serve-command-throws-error-an-unhandled-exception-occurred-project#57648315)

I did find this bugreport related to , but it's almost a year old and does seem to be resolved.
https://github.com/Azure/ng-deploy-azure/pull/92

My questions:
What else is in play here, that would disrupt me from deploying?

What mistakes did I make in the files presented?

How come angular CLI doesn't find my active subscriptions? One and a half years ago I know it was possible with free subscriptions and documentations doesn't state otherwise?

[image]
[image]

Half the time when I log into Microsoft with my account it states 'We couldn't find an account with that username. Try another..' But I know for sure this is the good account because when I want to login with another account it says I can't because I'm logged in with the account he can't find (I'm not even joking)

I'd like to get it up and running before I scale up to a bigger/more costly AppServicePlan, just to avoid having all that mess while on paying service :)

Am I asking too much? ))

Thanks for helping

Comment: Here is an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/ng-deploy-azure/issues/85) on GitHub with the same problem you can refer to.

Comment: @HiGuy Yes I've seen that GitHub issue, followed the S/O link (as mentioned in my question) and did what was suggested: point browserTargets to projectName & add 'server', 'serve-ssr' & 'prerender' to architect in angular.json. I still get Project target does not exist when I ng run projectName:deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem was abandoning the deployment through Angular CLI, add a new subscription, moving everything to that new subscription and deploy though azure deployment center